# Simple Smart Phone detection

Tags: php, user-agent, jquery-mobile, smartphone, mobile-devices

Ok I've seen a couple of mobile detection scripts that look to identify all mobile handsets, anyone come up with a simple Smart Phone detection script?

I'm using the [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) framework and wanted to theme based on device, Am I going about this the wrong way or are there any tips one could give?

What defines a Smart Phone?

What I've seen but I think are way to complex for smartphone detection:

- [HDAPI](http://code.google.com/p/hdapi/)
- [Zend UserAgent](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html)
- [PHP get_browser()](http://docs.php.net/get_browser)
- [WURFL PHP API](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/nphp/)
- [PHP Lightweight Mobile Detection](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php)

I like this function here but still needs to be trimmed down:

```
/**
 * A simple class used to detect whether page<br>
 * is being viewed from a mobile device or not.
 * @copyright 2010 Covac Software
 * @author Christian Sciberras
 * @version 01/05/2010
 */
class Mobile {
    public static function is_mobile(){
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // get the user agent value - this should be cleaned to ensure no nefarious input gets executed
        $accept     = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; // get the content accept value - this should be cleaned to ensure no nefarious input gets executed
        return false
            || (preg_match('/ipad/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/ipod/i',$user_agent)||preg_match('/iphone/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/android/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/opera mini/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/blackberry/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/(pre\/|palm os|palm|hiptop|avantgo|plucker|xiino|blazer|elaine)/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/(iris|3g_t|windows ce|opera mobi|windows ce; smartphone;|windows ce; iemobile)/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/(mini 9.5|vx1000|lge |m800|e860|u940|ux840|compal|wireless| mobi|ahong|lg380|lgku|lgu900|lg210|lg47|lg920|lg840|lg370|sam-r|mg50|s55|g83|t66|vx400|mk99|d615|d763|el370|sl900|mp500|samu3|samu4|vx10|xda_|samu5|samu6|samu7|samu9|a615|b832|m881|s920|n210|s700|c-810|_h797|mob-x|sk16d|848b|mowser|s580|r800|471x|v120|rim8|c500foma:|160x|x160|480x|x640|t503|w839|i250|sprint|w398samr810|m5252|c7100|mt126|x225|s5330|s820|htil-g1|fly v71|s302|-x113|novarra|k610i|-three|8325rc|8352rc|sanyo|vx54|c888|nx250|n120|mtk |c5588|s710|t880|c5005|i;458x|p404i|s210|c5100|teleca|s940|c500|s590|foma|samsu|vx8|vx9|a1000|_mms|myx|a700|gu1100|bc831|e300|ems100|me701|me702m-three|sd588|s800|8325rc|ac831|mw200|brew |d88|htc\/|htc_touch|355x|m50|km100|d736|p-9521|telco|sl74|ktouch|m4u\/|me702|8325rc|kddi|phone|lg |sonyericsson|samsung|240x|x320|vx10|nokia|sony cmd|motorola|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|kindle|mobile|psp|treo)/i',$user_agent))
            || ((strpos($accept,'text/vnd.wap.wml')>0)||(strpos($accept,'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0))
            || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE'])||isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']))
            || (in_array(strtolower(substr($user_agent,0,4)),array('1207'=>'1207','3gso'=>'3gso','4thp'=>'4thp','501i'=>'501i','502i'=>'502i','503i'=>'503i','504i'=>'504i','505i'=>'505i','506i'=>'506i','6310'=>'6310','6590'=>'6590','770s'=>'770s','802s'=>'802s','a wa'=>'a wa','acer'=>'acer','acs-'=>'acs-','airn'=>'airn','alav'=>'alav','asus'=>'asus','attw'=>'attw','au-m'=>'au-m','aur '=>'aur ','aus '=>'aus ','abac'=>'abac','acoo'=>'acoo','aiko'=>'aiko','alco'=>'alco','alca'=>'alca','amoi'=>'amoi','anex'=>'anex','anny'=>'anny','anyw'=>'anyw','aptu'=>'aptu','arch'=>'arch','argo'=>'argo','bell'=>'bell','bird'=>'bird','bw-n'=>'bw-n','bw-u'=>'bw-u','beck'=>'beck','benq'=>'benq','bilb'=>'bilb','blac'=>'blac','c55/'=>'c55/','cdm-'=>'cdm-','chtm'=>'chtm','capi'=>'capi','cond'=>'cond','craw'=>'craw','dall'=>'dall','dbte'=>'dbte','dc-s'=>'dc-s','dica'=>'dica','ds-d'=>'ds-d','ds12'=>'ds12','dait'=>'dait','devi'=>'devi','dmob'=>'dmob','doco'=>'doco','dopo'=>'dopo','el49'=>'el49','erk0'=>'erk0','esl8'=>'esl8','ez40'=>'ez40','ez60'=>'ez60','ez70'=>'ez70','ezos'=>'ezos','ezze'=>'ezze','elai'=>'elai','emul'=>'emul','eric'=>'eric','ezwa'=>'ezwa','fake'=>'fake','fly-'=>'fly-','fly_'=>'fly_','g-mo'=>'g-mo','g1 u'=>'g1 u','g560'=>'g560','gf-5'=>'gf-5','grun'=>'grun','gene'=>'gene','go.w'=>'go.w','good'=>'good','grad'=>'grad','hcit'=>'hcit','hd-m'=>'hd-m','hd-p'=>'hd-p','hd-t'=>'hd-t','hei-'=>'hei-','hp i'=>'hp i','hpip'=>'hpip','hs-c'=>'hs-c','htc '=>'htc ','htc-'=>'htc-','htca'=>'htca','htcg'=>'htcg','htcp'=>'htcp','htcs'=>'htcs','htct'=>'htct','htc_'=>'htc_','haie'=>'haie','hita'=>'hita','huaw'=>'huaw','hutc'=>'hutc','i-20'=>'i-20','i-go'=>'i-go','i-ma'=>'i-ma','i230'=>'i230','iac'=>'iac','iac-'=>'iac-','iac/'=>'iac/','ig01'=>'ig01','im1k'=>'im1k','inno'=>'inno','iris'=>'iris','jata'=>'jata','java'=>'java','kddi'=>'kddi','kgt'=>'kgt','kgt/'=>'kgt/','kpt '=>'kpt ','kwc-'=>'kwc-','klon'=>'klon','lexi'=>'lexi','lg g'=>'lg g','lg-a'=>'lg-a','lg-b'=>'lg-b','lg-c'=>'lg-c','lg-d'=>'lg-d','lg-f'=>'lg-f','lg-g'=>'lg-g','lg-k'=>'lg-k','lg-l'=>'lg-l','lg-m'=>'lg-m','lg-o'=>'lg-o','lg-p'=>'lg-p','lg-s'=>'lg-s','lg-t'=>'lg-t','lg-u'=>'lg-u','lg-w'=>'lg-w','lg/k'=>'lg/k','lg/l'=>'lg/l','lg/u'=>'lg/u','lg50'=>'lg50','lg54'=>'lg54','lge-'=>'lge-','lge/'=>'lge/','lynx'=>'lynx','leno'=>'leno','m1-w'=>'m1-w','m3ga'=>'m3ga','m50/'=>'m50/','maui'=>'maui','mc01'=>'mc01','mc21'=>'mc21','mcca'=>'mcca','medi'=>'medi','meri'=>'meri','mio8'=>'mio8','mioa'=>'mioa','mo01'=>'mo01','mo02'=>'mo02','mode'=>'mode','modo'=>'modo','mot '=>'mot ','mot-'=>'mot-','mt50'=>'mt50','mtp1'=>'mtp1','mtv '=>'mtv ','mate'=>'mate','maxo'=>'maxo','merc'=>'merc','mits'=>'mits','mobi'=>'mobi','motv'=>'motv','mozz'=>'mozz','n100'=>'n100','n101'=>'n101','n102'=>'n102','n202'=>'n202','n203'=>'n203','n300'=>'n300','n302'=>'n302','n500'=>'n500','n502'=>'n502','n505'=>'n505','n700'=>'n700','n701'=>'n701','n710'=>'n710','nec-'=>'nec-','nem-'=>'nem-','newg'=>'newg','neon'=>'neon','netf'=>'netf','noki'=>'noki','nzph'=>'nzph','o2 x'=>'o2 x','o2-x'=>'o2-x','opwv'=>'opwv','owg1'=>'owg1','opti'=>'opti','oran'=>'oran','p800'=>'p800','pand'=>'pand','pg-1'=>'pg-1','pg-2'=>'pg-2','pg-3'=>'pg-3','pg-6'=>'pg-6','pg-8'=>'pg-8','pg-c'=>'pg-c','pg13'=>'pg13','phil'=>'phil','pn-2'=>'pn-2','pt-g'=>'pt-g','palm'=>'palm','pana'=>'pana','pire'=>'pire','pock'=>'pock','pose'=>'pose','psio'=>'psio','qa-a'=>'qa-a','qc-2'=>'qc-2','qc-3'=>'qc-3','qc-5'=>'qc-5','qc-7'=>'qc-7','qc07'=>'qc07','qc12'=>'qc12','qc21'=>'qc21','qc32'=>'qc32','qc60'=>'qc60','qci-'=>'qci-','qwap'=>'qwap','qtek'=>'qtek','r380'=>'r380','r600'=>'r600','raks'=>'raks','rim9'=>'rim9','rove'=>'rove','s55/'=>'s55/','sage'=>'sage','sams'=>'sams','sc01'=>'sc01','sch-'=>'sch-','scp-'=>'scp-','sdk/'=>'sdk/','se47'=>'se47','sec-'=>'sec-','sec0'=>'sec0','sec1'=>'sec1','semc'=>'semc','sgh-'=>'sgh-','shar'=>'shar','sie-'=>'sie-','sk-0'=>'sk-0','sl45'=>'sl45','slid'=>'slid','smb3'=>'smb3','smt5'=>'smt5','sp01'=>'sp01','sph-'=>'sph-','spv '=>'spv ','spv-'=>'spv-','sy01'=>'sy01','samm'=>'samm','sany'=>'sany','sava'=>'sava','scoo'=>'scoo','send'=>'send','siem'=>'siem','smar'=>'smar','smit'=>'smit','soft'=>'soft','sony'=>'sony','t-mo'=>'t-mo','t218'=>'t218','t250'=>'t250','t600'=>'t600','t610'=>'t610','t618'=>'t618','tcl-'=>'tcl-','tdg-'=>'tdg-','telm'=>'telm','tim-'=>'tim-','ts70'=>'ts70','tsm-'=>'tsm-','tsm3'=>'tsm3','tsm5'=>'tsm5','tx-9'=>'tx-9','tagt'=>'tagt','talk'=>'talk','teli'=>'teli','topl'=>'topl','hiba'=>'hiba','up.b'=>'up.b','upg1'=>'upg1','utst'=>'utst','v400'=>'v400','v750'=>'v750','veri'=>'veri','vk-v'=>'vk-v','vk40'=>'vk40','vk50'=>'vk50','vk52'=>'vk52','vk53'=>'vk53','vm40'=>'vm40','vx98'=>'vx98','virg'=>'virg','vite'=>'vite','voda'=>'voda','vulc'=>'vulc','w3c '=>'w3c ','w3c-'=>'w3c-','wapj'=>'wapj','wapp'=>'wapp','wapu'=>'wapu','wapm'=>'wapm','wig '=>'wig ','wapi'=>'wapi','wapr'=>'wapr','wapv'=>'wapv','wapy'=>'wapy','wapa'=>'wapa','waps'=>'waps','wapt'=>'wapt','winc'=>'winc','winw'=>'winw','wonu'=>'wonu','x700'=>'x700','xda2'=>'xda2','xdag'=>'xdag','yas-'=>'yas-','your'=>'your','zte-'=>'zte-','zeto'=>'zeto','acs-'=>'acs-','alav'=>'alav','alca'=>'alca','amoi'=>'amoi','aste'=>'aste','audi'=>'audi','avan'=>'avan','benq'=>'benq','bird'=>'bird','blac'=>'blac','blaz'=>'blaz','brew'=>'brew','brvw'=>'brvw','bumb'=>'bumb','ccwa'=>'ccwa','cell'=>'cell','cldc'=>'cldc','cmd-'=>'cmd-','dang'=>'dang','doco'=>'doco','eml2'=>'eml2','eric'=>'eric','fetc'=>'fetc','hipt'=>'hipt','http'=>'http','ibro'=>'ibro','idea'=>'idea','ikom'=>'ikom','inno'=>'inno','ipaq'=>'ipaq','jbro'=>'jbro','jemu'=>'jemu','java'=>'java','jigs'=>'jigs','kddi'=>'kddi','keji'=>'keji','kyoc'=>'kyoc','kyok'=>'kyok','leno'=>'leno','lg-c'=>'lg-c','lg-d'=>'lg-d','lg-g'=>'lg-g','lge-'=>'lge-','libw'=>'libw','m-cr'=>'m-cr','maui'=>'maui','maxo'=>'maxo','midp'=>'midp','mits'=>'mits','mmef'=>'mmef','mobi'=>'mobi','mot-'=>'mot-','moto'=>'moto','mwbp'=>'mwbp','mywa'=>'mywa','nec-'=>'nec-','newt'=>'newt','nok6'=>'nok6','noki'=>'noki','o2im'=>'o2im','opwv'=>'opwv','palm'=>'palm','pana'=>'pana','pant'=>'pant','pdxg'=>'pdxg','phil'=>'phil','play'=>'play','pluc'=>'pluc','port'=>'port','prox'=>'prox','qtek'=>'qtek','qwap'=>'qwap','rozo'=>'rozo','sage'=>'sage','sama'=>'sama','sams'=>'sams','sany'=>'sany','sch-'=>'sch-','sec-'=>'sec-','send'=>'send','seri'=>'seri','sgh-'=>'sgh-','shar'=>'shar','sie-'=>'sie-','siem'=>'siem','smal'=>'smal','smar'=>'smar','sony'=>'sony','sph-'=>'sph-','symb'=>'symb','t-mo'=>'t-mo','teli'=>'teli','tim-'=>'tim-','tosh'=>'tosh','treo'=>'treo','tsm-'=>'tsm-','upg1'=>'upg1','upsi'=>'upsi','vk-v'=>'vk-v','voda'=>'voda','vx52'=>'vx52','vx53'=>'vx53','vx60'=>'vx60','vx61'=>'vx61','vx70'=>'vx70','vx80'=>'vx80','vx81'=>'vx81','vx83'=>'vx83','vx85'=>'vx85','wap-'=>'wap-','wapa'=>'wapa','wapi'=>'wapi','wapp'=>'wapp','wapr'=>'wapr','webc'=>'webc','whit'=>'whit','winw'=>'winw','wmlb'=>'wmlb','xda-'=>'xda-',)))
        ;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Another approach I thought of was the [Mobile OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_operating_system) and then filter by device, ANyone have thoughts on this?

- [Another interesting link: PHP to Detect Browser and Operating System](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/2562-php-to-detect-browser-and-operating-system/)

Comment: What do you mean by "needs to be trimmed down"? What's wrong if the function isn't trimmed down.

Comment: Would like to only check for Smartphones, but trying to define what is a smartphone as well. I think that function is checking for mobile. I was thinking if the device supported HTML5 or something like that. Think Modern Smartphone

Comment: www.handsetdetection.com has pretty good API to detect mobile devices

Comment: +1 as it looks nice, checking out the free version

Comment: @criticus please post this comment as a answer

Comment: @Phill Pafford ok, will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many different mobile devices and so little standardization, and you probably would need to update your detection script from time to time as well as add new devices to the list.  I found that [www.handsetdetection.com](http://www.handsetdetection.com) has pretty complete list of handsets you can download. Also you can use their API for the real time detection on their side. 
I don't know how it works on your app but I'd recommend to add detection info to your users' cookies in order to make api calls only for the unique devices.

Here is an example how I did this in startup plugin for ZF project

```
class Application_Plugin_HandsetDetection extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{

    $cookies = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Cookies');
    if ($cookies->isVersion('mobile')) {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($mobile);
    }

    if ($cookies->isVersion('full')){
        return;
    }

    $device = new Application_Service_HandsetDetection();
    if (!$device->isMobile()) {
        $cookies->setVersion('full');
        return;
    }

    $cookies->setVersion('mobile');

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($mobile);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not pretty sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve and with "wanted to theme based on device".

So, will you put a BlackBerry logo if the user has a BlackBerry device (so it should be dependent on the manufacturer) or will your web app be denpendent on the screen size? Or depenedent on the features of HTML5/CSS3?

Also in web development I try to do one website for all. The same I do with jQuery Mobile and it works great. I did one design, which works for Opera (Win), Firefox (Win + Mac), IE9, Safari (Win, Mac, iPad), Google Chrome (Win). And I do no CSS hacks!
Your web app should be nearly independent of the screen size, I only have css media limitations and some JavaScript functions which design the page.

If you want to check the HTML5 / CSS3 support of the webbrowser, you should never check the mobile device itself, you need to check the function itself.
So, bad style is checking if the webbrowser is IE in version 7, 8, 9, because you will never know which function will work in which version. You check the functionality you need. And this can be done with Modernizr:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#modernizr

http://www.modernizr.com/

Other checks, jQuery can handle it.

Comment: jquery mobile does what modernizr does. as of now a mobile device can easily be determined by the viewport size. Also - google: `progressive enhancement`

Comment: MOdernizer is the preffered JS to use now a days to detect many browser capabilities. Works well.