# Tablet Detection

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, tablet, mobile-devices

Okay I got some good advice for [Mobile Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122566/simple-smart-phone-detection) but still having an issue with themed tablets as the icons will be larger for a tablet view then a mobile device. I'm using jQueryMobile as the framework and it does detect the iPad (And I'm sure other tablets are on the way), but how can I detect if it's a tablet or mobile device? would I just go with the screen size?

If that's the case than what's the largest screen size for a mobile device or the smallest screen for a tablet?

is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile adds classes to the body tag which allows you to create a single CSS for all the devices.

See here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/mediahelpers.html

**update**

As of beta2 helpers will be deprecated and set for removal. You should take a look at `media queries` which were used to put these classes in there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using media queries and targeting a different CSS stylesheet.

Comment: yes I understand I need a different CSS style sheet per device group but wanted to know how to determine the device?

Comment: Well you can't, as far as I'm aware, target each device separately, but can use media queries (http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to target different screen sizes, which should help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever considered a device detection library like [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), [tera-wurfl](http://www.tera-wurfl.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or the proprietary [deviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/about)?

Comment: yeah I have looked at them, thanks. I do see the need for them in future projects +1

Comment: Keep an eye on the licensing though! We just decided not to use the wurfl java api because it comes with an AGPL licence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the benefits of server side detection? OpenDDR offers .NET and Java libraries, licensed under LGPL.

You can have a look at http://www.openddr.org

Comment: Let me know when you offer a PHP or Python flavor

Answer (score 0):

We are starting to develop using Formfactor detection libraries such as [FormfactorJS](https://github.com/PaulKinlan/formfactor) - note, I created this.

The theory being using the same semantic HTML, you can specialize your CSS and Javascript using for a given class of device (smartphone, tablet, desktop etc) whilst also being cognizant of responsive design to individual device profile using Media Queries.